# how to create a multi-node redshift cluster only for prod using Terraform

Tags: amazon-redshift, terraform

I have 2 redshift cluster prod and dev , i am using the same terraform module.
How can i have 2 nodes only for prod cluster . Please let me know the what is the interpolation syntax i should be using

```
variable "node_type" {
  default = "dc1.large"
}

resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "****" {
  cluster_identifier           = "abc-${var.env}"
  node_type                    = "${var.node_type}"
  cluster_type                 = "single-node" ==> multi node
  number_of_nodes              = 2 ==> only for prod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [map type](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html):

```
variable "node_type" {
  default = "dc1.large"
}

variable "env" {
  default = "development"
}

variable "redshift_cluster_type" {
    type = "map"

  default = {
    development = "single-node"
    production  = "multi-node"
  }
}

variable "redshift_node" {
    type = "map"

  default = {
    development = "1"
    production  = "2"
  }
}    

resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "****" {
  cluster_identifier           = "abc-${var.env}"
  node_type                    = "${var.node_type}"
  cluster_type                 = "${var.redshift_cluster_type[var.env]}"
  number_of_nodes              = "${var.redshift_node[var.env]}"
}
```

Sometime I am lazy, and just do this

```
resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "****" {
  cluster_identifier           = "abc-${var.env}"
  node_type                    = "${var.node_type}"
  cluster_type                 = "${var.env == "production" ? "multi_node" : "single_node" }"
  number_of_nodes              = "${var.env == "production" ? 2 : 1 }"
}
```

Comment: can we use empty value? like for example - we want snapshot only for prod and for dev an empty cluster
snapshot_identifier          = "${var.env == "production" ? "xxxx" : " " }" @BMW

Comment: Yes that's possible, you have to put null as value in your condition : snapshot_identifier = var.env == "production" ? "xxxx" : null